# Angular- Scanner.js - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'processScannedImage' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

We are working on Angular application that integrates with a TWAIN scanner, using scanner.js

We can get successfully get the image from the scanner but, the problem we got is after we process the scanned image we get the following error

> Cannot read property 'processScannedImage' of undefined

we believe that the errors is coming from `this scoping` issue but we do not know what is exactly.Here is the used code as in scanner.js docs, but we converted it into TS

```
import '../../../assets/scripts/scanner.js';
import { TypeFormatterService } from 'app/main/services/type-formatter.service';

declare let scanner;



  /** Processes a ScannedImage */
  private processScannedImage(scannedImage): any {
    console.log(scannedImage)

    scannedImage = this.typeFormatter.caseRequestImageFormat(scannedImage);

    console.log(scannedImage)

    this._scannedImages.push(scannedImage);
    const elementImg = scanner.createDomElementFromModel({
      'name': 'img',
      'attributes': {
        'class': 'scanned',
        'src': scannedImage.src
      }
    });
    document.getElementById('images').appendChild(elementImg);

    console.log(this._scannedImages);
  }

  /** Processes the scan result */
  private displayImagesOnPage(successful, mesg, response): any {
    if (!successful) { // On error
      console.error('Failed: ' + mesg);
      return;
    }

    // User canceled.
    if (successful && mesg !== null && mesg.toLowerCase().indexOf('user cancel') >= 0) {
      console.log('User canceled');
      return;
    }

    // returns an array of ScannedImage
    // function getScannedImages(response, includeOriginals, includeThumbnails)
    const that = this;
    const scannedImages = scanner.getScannedImages(response, true, false);
    for (let i = 0; (scannedImages instanceof Array) && i < scannedImages.length; i++) {
      const scannedImage = scannedImages[i];
      that.processScannedImage(scannedImage);
    }
  }

  public scanToJpg() {
    const that = this;
    scanner.scan(that.displayImagesOnPage,
      {
        'show_scanner_ui': false, // Whether scanner UI should be shown
        'output_settings':
          [
            {
              'type': 'return-base64',
              'format': 'jpg'
            }
          ]
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried it with `this.processScannedImage`?

Comment: yes and it is giving the same error!

Comment: Do you get an error by calling the method directly? `processScannedImages()`

Comment: yes also can not calling it directly, i believe the error with scope by i do not know why exactly this happened we tried to prevent this by having a reference for this inn "that" variable but with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is an issue with the scope.  When the scanner.js plugin calls the displayImagesOnPage function from the line `scanner.scan(that.displayImagesOnPage`  it looses the scope of your current class.  In order to pass the scope along with the function, you can bind the scope to the function.

This is how I got it to work:

`scanner.scan(this.displayImagesOnPage.bind(this)`